# How to call a controller method from application-context.xml in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I have a class widgetController in my project and I have to call it's method to repeat in every 5 mins using spring timerTask. Existing code is like this ...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/widget/**")
public class WidgetController {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Timed
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loadProductsRailWidget/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getProductsRailWidget(){
    /////some code here 
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

now I have made required entries in application-context.xml,

```html
<bean id ="widgetController" class="com.atul.web.controller.WidgetController">
</bean>

<bean id="timerTaskFactoryBean"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.MethodInvokingTimerTaskFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="widgetController"></property>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="getProductsRailWidget"></property>
</bean>
    
<bean id="timerTask"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.ScheduledTimerTask">
    <property name="timerTask" ref="timerTaskFactoryBean"></property>
    <property name="period" value="300000"></property>
</bean>
    
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.timer.TimerFactoryBean">
    <property name="scheduledTimerTasks">
        <list>
            <ref local="timerTask"></ref>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

now I have tested above configuration with a dummy class TestRepeat instead of existing controller class, it was working fine. But unable to call controller's method. I'm new to spring so not sure how to achieve this, earlier in my project WidgetController didn't have entry in application-context.xml but it's method is called from a *.jsp using url "/widget/loadProductsRailWidget/".

now how to achieve this, kindly let me know some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Although the `WidgetController` is a Spring managed bean, it's primary aim is to respond to http requests matching the pattern specified in `RequestMapping`. So the code in the method `getProductsRailWidget` will only run when you send a http request to your webapplication at `/widget/loadProductsRailWidget/`. If you want to run this method multiple times using a timer then probably you need to have a mechanism ( for e.g., using javascript timer code running in a browser) to send it request multiple times. For other means to run the code using Spring task scheduler you take a look [here](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/23/4-ways-to-schedule-tasks-in-spring-3-scheduled-example/).

Comment: Thanks Shailendra but can't I send HTTPRequest from another class?

Comment: You do not need a http request and a handler (controller) to schedule a timer which fires after some time. You can just declare it in spring context and let the Spring scheduler infrastructure manage that.